# Laravel: Loop on booleans to check TRUE and FALSE

Tags: php, laravel

I need a little help here. I have relations setup in my laravel env I want to retrieve all the `slots` which are marked `taken`.

So it's simply looping on each slot and checking if `taken` is true or false.

here is what I had in mind.. and been trying

```
$plateCont = \App\Models\PlateContainer::find(7);
  return   $freeslots = $plateCont->containerSlots()->get();


  foreach ($freeslots as $slot)
  {
    if($slot->where('taken', false))
    {
      return $slot->lists('slot');
    }
    // return $slots;
  }
```

for this I get `200` status code but nothing displayed. Would you show me a good way to do this.

Its simply fetching all the slots of the specified `id` and check if they are `taken`. If they are not `taken` return the slots otherwise return `all` the slots

**update** chaining `get()` behind `containerSlots()`. Foreach is returning every thing.

```
[
    1,
    7,
    9,
    5,
    3,
    5,
    4,
    3,
    2,
    1,
    5,
    1,
    8,
    9,
    8,
    5,
    5,
    1,
    8,
    5,
    1,
    5,
    8,
    8,
    4,
    5,
    8,
    4,
    2,
    1
]
```

Comment: `print_r($freeslots)` please

Comment: @aldrin27 which line?

Comment: @user3641381 before `foreach`

Comment: @madforstrength I have added `get()` after `containerSlots()` but afterwards the foreeach is returning all the `slots`.   I have updated the code

Comment: @aldrin27 updated. Check please

Comment: @user3641381 you are returning collection in the start? How would it reach to foreach condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_filter)

```
$freeslots = $plateCont->containerSlots->filter(function($item) {
    return $item->taken;
})
```

Comment: I gave this a try earlier. It returns `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter()`

Comment: @user3641381 It should be `$plateCont->containerSlots->filter`. A property, not a method. Property returns Collection, method returns relation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get only `slot` that are `taken`

```
$freeslots = $plateCont->containerSlots()->where('taken', true)->get()
```